# Get index of value in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyType> ItemList`, and I need to know the index of a specific `MyType` in the collection.  However, when I hard-code the values like this:

```cs
ItemList.IndexOf(new MyType(val1, val2, val3));
```

it can't find the value because it is a different instance of `MyType`, even if all the values are the same.

So, I wrote this simple method:

```cs
private int IndexOfValInItemList(MenuItem val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ItemList[i].Title == val.Title && ItemList[i].Page == val.Page && ItemList[i].Menu == val.Menu) { return i; }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This is in the same class as the value and directly accesses the value.  I know that I could expand it to take any `ObservableCollection<MyType>`, but I haven't because `ItemList` cannot be passed by reference:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _itemList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ItemList
{
    get { return _itemList; }
    set
    {
        if (_itemList == value) return;
        _itemList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to implement this, or is there are different way?  Is there a way I could call `ItemList.IndexOf(MyType(...))` and override the equality operator used to check it?  I already tried overriding the `==` operator, and that did not work.

I will have a second `ObservableCollection<MyType>` soon as I finish implementing my ViewModel, so I would like to know a generic solution, but if I have to write a second method to get the value from that collection, that is OK too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132410%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly states how it looks for a matching value.

> This method determines equality using the default equality comparer `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` for `T`, the type of values in the list.

Which brings you to the [documentation for `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The Default property checks whether type `T` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface and, if so, returns an `EqualityComparer<T>`that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the overrides of `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` provided by `T`.

You need to be overriding `Equals` not the `==` operator. Changing the behavior of the `==` operator to something other than `Object.ReferenceEquals()` for reference types should only be considered in rare cases.